# How to use string.split( ) for the following string in javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I have the following string: `(17.591257793993833, 78.88544082641602)` in Javascript

How do I use split() for the above string so that I can get the numbers separately.

This is what I have tried (I know its wrong)

```
var location= "(17.591257793993833, 78.88544082641602)";
var sep= location.split("("" "," "")");    
document.getElementById("TextBox1").value= sep[1];
document.getElementById("Textbox2").value=sep[2];
```

Suggestions please

Comment: Dude. Don't use `location` as your variable name. It'll redirect you right away. Use `loc` or something else.

Comment: What's the actual rules you want to follow? As in, if you got other strings, are they always two numbers, are the brackets always there, is there always a space after the comma?

Comment: @Amaan Only if it's in the global (window) scope - this could be in a function and it should work just fine.

Comment: @Thor84no the string is always in the same format.

Comment: @Amaan Would like to know what happens  if I use location as variable  name in the global scope? Where will it redirect?

Comment: I'm sure there are already answers around that you can use, but just for future reference, I'd recommend not asking questions where you're limiting the solutions like this unless it's strictly necessary. In other words, don't ask how to use `string.split()` to solve the problem unless this is specifically important (which sounds like homework), instead define what you need to do and let people come up with alternative, possibly much better ways of solving it than you perhaps originally envisioned.

Comment: @Cdeez It will redirect as though you'd entered whatever you set the variable to in your browsers address bar (so it'd fail to look up the server in this case).

Comment: @Cdeez It'd redirect to whatever you assign to `location`. `location = 'http://google.com';` would redirect to Google.

Comment: @Thor84no Thanks for the suggestion, will keep in mind the next time I ask a question.

Comment: @Thor84no , Amaan : Ok I got it now. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use regular expression, something as simple as following would work:

```
// returns and array with two elements: [17.591257793993833, 78.88544082641602]
"(17.591257793993833, 78.88544082641602)".match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g)
```

Comment: `var sep= location.match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g);`
`document.getElementById("TextBox1").value= sep[0];`
`document.getElementById("TextBox2").value= sep[1];` But this isn't working. Where am I wrong? Its seems there are no capturing groups in the regex right?

Comment: It's something else because the script's working http://jsfiddle.net/8JR7j/ Maybe you're trying to assign values to TextBox1 and TextBox2 before they're present in the DOM? Checkout chrome console or firebug - are there any Javascript errors you see?

Comment: When I wrote: `document.getElementById("TextBox1").value= location;` ,it worked. I had the content of location in my textbox1. How do I check the chrome console? I am working in visual studio 2008 and it doesn't show any errors in javascript, even if there are. How do I check for errors? I am a noob in javascript

Comment: Run you page in chrome, press F12 key and you'll see console. Reload the page to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Ok I'm out of ideas then. Post your page somewhere so I can take a peek (pastebin.com or something).

Comment: `location` parameter passed to placeMarker function isn't a string that's why there is a Javascript error (once you click on a map), saying that there's no `.match()` method for location object. You have  to convert latLng object into a string using .toString() function: `var sep= location.toString().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g);`

Comment: Yes, but only after clicking on a map (since the bug was in a click event handler). Get familiar with console and `console.log()` to quickly debug this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could user Regular Expression. That would help you a lot. Together with the [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function.

A possible Regexp for you might be:

```
/\d+.\d+/g
```

For more information you can start with wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`. You can try the regex [here](http://regexr.com?32189).

In javascript you could do

```
var str = "(17.591257793993833, 78.88544082641602)";
str.match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g);
```

Check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values as numbers, i.e. `typeof x == "number"`, you would have to use a regular expression to get the numbers out and then convert those `String`s into `Number`s, i.e.

```
var numsStrings = location.match(/(\d+.\d+)/g),
    numbers = [],
    i, len = numsStrings.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    numbers.push(+numsStrings[i]);
}
```